# Dataset Designer Does Not Match Data Sources

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In VS2015, I have a table within a database in my Data Sources window.  It does not show up in the Dataset Designer.  When I go to Data Sources -> Database -> Configure with Wizard, the table shows up but it is unchecked.  If I check it, it puts a little arrow to the right of it and renames it TableName1 as though it already exists in the data set and we are adding it again.  I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project.  I tried closing VS and opening it again.  None of those things worked.  I'm really worried I'm going to lose a lot of work.

I would really appreciate any help in how to rebuild the Dataset Designer to match the Data Sources.  I ran the custom tool and that didn't work.  I tried opening it in VS2017 and the dataset was missing all kinds of things - much worse than with VS2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the BIN and the OBJ directories in the solution and it will solve the problem.  I didn't find this answer anywhere so I thought I would post it.  Not saying this will work for everyone but it worked for me.  When I got it back, some of my tables had no fields (just a little box with the table name) so I had to edit the query and put the select statement back in.